# Word link in Slack

Tags: slack

How can I create a word link in Slack?

By word link I mean a link which displays a word of my choice, and links to a URL independent of that word.

For instance, in SO it is achieved by typing the word in brackets and after that the link in parentheses, like this:
`[foo](https://example.com)`: 
[foo](https://example.com)

Comment: "This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center." Slack is a software actually ( :

Comment: I had the same question, this was helpful.  Also confused as to how it's not about computer hardware or software.

Comment: I wish I could add an answer to this, since no-one actually provide you with the way to do this...
In short: its possible, but only by using slack API for applications, and the application just need to format the text like this: `<http://www.example.com|This message *is* a link>` ([source](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#linking-urls))

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2020-02-24**

Thank you [newswim](https://superuser.com/users/429646/newswim) for pointing out this new feature.

See https://slack.com/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages :

> - Select text, then click the **link icon** in the formatting toolbar
> - Select text, then press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> on Windows/Linux.
>
> Copy the link you'd like to share and paste it in the empty field
>   under **Link**, then click **Save**.

---

<strike>This is not currently supported. See https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204399343-Share-links-in-Slack :</strike>

> **Share links**
>
> To share a link in Slack, just copy and paste the URL into the message field and send. Most links will automatically expand to show a preview of the web page. Here's an example from the desktop app:
>   [image]
>
> **Note: It’s not possible to hyperlink words in a Slack message.**

Comment: My question is why? it is allowed via the API so surely it is not a security thing. One response I've seen as to why is that slack is intended for a broad group of users and most people don't know basic markdown. But I don't buy that either as you can `*bold*`, `_italics_` etc. why not just add `[simple linking](www.example.com)`?

Comment: Not to say that the competition (I mean rocket.chat) supports such linking since forever - with the simple markdown you described.

Comment: They are now with the new WYSIWYG editor:

https://slack.com/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages

Comment: @newswim I am unable to test this, but are sure that it works? The note at the bottom of the page you linked reads: Note: To include a URL, paste it into the message input field — **it’s not currently possible to create hyperlinks in messages.**

Comment: It is possible now. Click the formatting button (hover over the text input field, the button reads "Aa"). Notice the link button, it's 6th from left.

Comment: Thank you @newswim. Updated my answer to reflect the new Slack functionality.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @wysiwyg, users are not allowed this ability.

On the other hand, applications are perfectly able to contribute hyperlinked text.  For example: https://slack.com/apps/A0F81R7U7-rss .  That app produces hyperlinked text into the integrated channel regularly.